# Java Pong - assign various reflection points to different parts of a paddle

Tags: java, swing

I'm making pong in Java and wanted to make the game more fun by assigning different reflection logic to each part of the paddle, like so:

(ball hittins outter edges of paddle will have a different effect than it hitting the middle of the paddle)

[image]

The paddle extends Rectangle2D so I could use Rectangle2D's `intersects()` method to determine if the ball has touched any part of it...

Is it possible to determine where exactly the ball has hit on the paddle?

What I'm planning to do is,

- calculate angle of incidence and reflective angle based on that...
- If the ball hits at a point x on the paddle... I will change the reflection angle accordingly

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @Dukeling so you're saying that an angle of incidence of 33 degrees would have a 57 degree reflection? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Correction to previous my comment: If you just mean a symmetric reflection (as in your image) (not sure if you do), I don't think `angleOfReflection = angleOfIncidence * 2` is right. I think they should be equal. But it does depend how you define the angles. The picture and definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_reflection#Reflection_of_light) may put us on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine where exactly the ball has hit on the paddle?

If it were me, I would grab the current co-ordinates of both the ball and the paddle. For the paddle, you can get two sets of y co-ordinates, to describe the line facing the ball. Ie:

```
int paddleY1 = paddle.y;
int paddleY2 = paddle.y + paddle.width;

// assuming the paddle can only go up and down, y is the only co-ordinate that matters.
```

Then, you can compute the mid point of the paddle as:

```
int paddleYMid = (paddleY1 + paddleY2) / 2;
```

You can find out if the ball hit the left or right side of the paddle by comparing the y co-ordinates. Ie:

```
if(ball.y > paddleYMid)
{
   // Right side of the paddle.
}
else
{
   // Left side of the paddle.
}
```

Then it's up to you to develop further refinement.

Comment: This may be off by a tiny bit, considering the ball can probably go quite a few pixels into the paddle if it moves that many pixels at once, or as little as just 1 pixel, but fixing that is probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Aye, I think my answer deals with the main concept. OP can work out the details :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the paddle is always vertical (parallel to Y axis), the point of collision of the ball and the paddle will happen at the same y-coordinate as the center of the ball. That is:

```
if (ball.centerX - ball.radius <= paddle.rightX && ball.velocityX < 0)
{
    // collision point, if any, is at (ball.centerX - ball.radius, ball.centerY)
    if (ball.centerY >= paddle.bottomY && ball.centerY <= paddle.topY)
    {
        // handle collision
    }
}
```

As for the handling of the collision itself, you may not have to deal with angle of reflection, etc, but work solely with the raw values of x and y velocity. For example, to simulate a perfectly elastic collision, simply do:

```
ball.velocityX = -ball.velocityX;
```

And to account for ball reflecting at a higher or lower angle, you can scale the y velocity based on the position of the collision from the center of the paddle, eg.

```
ball.velocityY += SCALE_CONSTANT * (ball.centerY - ((paddle.topY + paddle.bottomY) / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the exact spot where the ball hits the paddle, you can formulate the problem as a line intersection problem.
The paddle can be represented as a vertical line at the x-coordinate (+thickness if needed, and corrected for the balls diameter) of the paddle. The ball can then be represented as a line along its movement vector (this line could be simply defined by its current position and its *next* position if it were to move unimpended).

The problem can now be solved using a line intersection algorythm.

Since the paddle is a vertical line, the equations can be simplified to just answer the question at which Y will the ball pass the paddle's X. Thats also a common problem encountered and solved by line clipping: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping (the intersection points can also be computed directly, but I can't find the formula atm).